# Yammer Bulk User Group Update?

Tags: yammer

We are currently using the Business' Yammer network as a way to keep track of incident management updates. There are several groups that have been created to handle various different types of escalation matters and so on. The team that need to use these groups need to all be members of each of these groups. Will there ever be a way to use a csv file through the Bulk User Update section to add a list of network members to each of these groups?

Comment: I managed to solve my own problem. Persistence seems to always pay off.

Comment: I found this useful, though it should probably have been posted to SuperUser or Sharepoint StackExchange sites (though not really a great fit on SE in general).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my own problem. Persistence seems to always pay off.

Turns out it can be done right from the groups main setting page. Clicking on the gear icon and selecting Import from Address Book. From Here you can use a .csv file with the headers First Name, Last Name, E-mail Address and the details filled in, a contact per line.